# How, in Perl 5, can I get the pid of the process who sent me a signal?

Tags: perl, signals

In C, I can say

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int continue_running = 1;

void handler(int signal, siginfo_t* info, void* data) {
    printf("got signal %d from process %d running as user %d\n",
        signal, info->si_pid, info->si_uid);
    continue_running = 0;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigset_t mask;

    sigemptyset(&mask);

    sa.sa_sigaction = &handler;
    sa.sa_mask      = mask;
    sa.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);

    printf("pid is %d\n", getpid());

    while (continue_running) { sleep(1); };

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out something like

```
pid is 31980
got signal 15 from process 31985 running as user 1000
```

when sent a `SIGTERM` from process 31985.

I can write similar Perl 5 code using `POSIX::sigaction`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;
use Data::Dumper;

my $sigset = POSIX::SigSet->new;

$sigset->emptyset;

my $sa = POSIX::SigAction->new(
    sub { print "caught signal\n" . Dumper \@_; $a = 0 },
    $sigset,
);

$sa->flags(POSIX::SA_SIGINFO);

$sa->safe(1); #defer the signal until we are in a safe place in the intrepeter

POSIX::sigaction(POSIX::SIGTERM, $sa);

print "$$\n";

$a = 1;
sleep 1 while $a;
```

But the handler still only receives one argument (the signal).  How can I get at `siginfo_t` structure?  Do have to write my own XS code that sets up its own handler and then passes the information on to a Perl callback?  Will writing my own handler in XS screw up the interpreter in some way?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.  It’s a tremendously excellent question. Have you looked at the existing XS code from the POSIX module? I haven’t, but I bet that’s where the answer to your question resides. As for screwing up the interpreter, are you aware of the “safe signals” change to the interpreter loop?

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I know about the change that happened at some point in the 5.8 line.  That is sort of what I worried about.  I don't know how to interface with how that stuff works.  Reading the POSIX XS stuff is probably the way to go.  I was hoping someone had already done the hard work for me.

Comment: If @tchrist likes it, thats good enough for me: +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`sighandler` (found in `mg.c`) is the wrapper around the Perl signal handler sub. As you can see, it is capabable of sending the information you want to the Perl signal handler sub.

```
#if defined(HAS_SIGACTION) && defined(SA_SIGINFO)
    {
        struct sigaction oact;

        if (sigaction(sig, 0, &oact) == 0 && oact.sa_flags & SA_SIGINFO) {
            if (sip) {
                HV *sih = newHV();
                SV *rv  = newRV_noinc(MUTABLE_SV(sih));
                /* The siginfo fields signo, code, errno, pid, uid,
                 * addr, status, and band are defined by POSIX/SUSv3. */
                (void)hv_stores(sih, "signo", newSViv(sip->si_signo));
                (void)hv_stores(sih, "code", newSViv(sip->si_code));
#if 0 /* XXX TODO: Configure scan for the existence of these, but even that does not help if the SA_SIGINFO is not implemented according to the spec. */
                hv_stores(sih, "errno",      newSViv(sip->si_errno));
                hv_stores(sih, "status",     newSViv(sip->si_status));
                hv_stores(sih, "uid",        newSViv(sip->si_uid));
                hv_stores(sih, "pid",        newSViv(sip->si_pid));
                hv_stores(sih, "addr",       newSVuv(PTR2UV(sip->si_addr)));
                hv_stores(sih, "band",       newSViv(sip->si_band));
#endif
                EXTEND(SP, 2);
                PUSHs(rv);
                mPUSHp((char *)sip, sizeof(*sip));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The information you want would be in the last parameter, although you'd have to unpack `*sip` yourself Perl-side. The catch is that the above code isn't getting excercised. Specifically, `sip` is always `NULL`.

---

Under unsafe signals, `sighandler` is called from `csighandler`, Perl's C-level signal handler. It currently doesn't pass on the pertinent information to `signalhandler`, but that's easily fixed.

```
-Perl_csighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *sip PERL_UNUSED_DECL, void *uap PERL_UNUSED_DECL)
+Perl_csighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *sip, void *uap PERL_UNUSED_DECL)
-       (*PL_sighandlerp)(sig, NULL, NULL);
+       (*PL_sighandlerp)(sig, sip, NULL);
```

Sample run:

```
$ PERL_SIGNALS=unsafe ./perl -Ilib a.pl
31213
caught signal
$VAR1 = [
          'TERM',
          {
            'code' => 0,
            'signo' => 15
          },
          '...*sip as "packed/binary" string...'
        ];
```

---

Under safe signals, `sighandler` is called from `despatch_signals` (sic) via `PERL_ASYNC_CHECK`. Unfortunately, the `*sip` previously received by `csighandler` is no longer available. To fix this, `csighandler` would have to queue a copy of `*sip` for `despatch_signals` to fetch.

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking into what it would take to make Perl 5.15 always pass a second arg with the siginfo_t data in a hashref to signal handlers if `SA_SIGINFO` is defined and the `feature` pragma is on.

Comment: Apparently I was looking at the 5.8.8 code, 5.14 seems to already have a lot of what needs to be done, as your code shows.  Now my question is why it isn't working for me in 5.14.

Comment: Am I crazy, or does that code make no sense?  It is creating `sih` which looks to me like an anonymous hashref, but then it never uses it.  It pushes `sip` on the stack instead.

Comment: Nevermind, I am crazy, `rv` is the reference to `sih` and it is being pushed on the stack by the `PUSHs`.

Comment: So, from looking at that code, either `oact.sa_flags` must not be getting set to `SA_SIGINFO` (even though I am asking for it to be set) or `POSIX::sigaction` doesn't use the same handler as `$SIG{TERM}`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm missing something too. It looks like it's passing a hash ref as arg, but it's not what I get from `perl -MData::Dumper -E'$SIG{USR1} = sub { print(Dumper(\@_)); }; sleep;'`

Comment: @Chas. Owens, `oact.sa_flags & SA_SIGINFO` is false for my command. I stupidly assumed the `if` was being entered.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, For your script, `oact.sa_flags & SA_SIGINFO` is `4`, but `sip` is `NULL`.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, @tchrist, Updated my answer.