# Capture the pid of signal sender

Tags: perl, signals

```
local $SIG{INT}  = \&handle_sigint;
sub handle_sigint {
    print "received sigint\n";

}
```

in handle_sigint i would like to print who (pid/process name) sent the signal.
Is there a way to capture that info in perl?

i can do this in C and this is ported to python as a module
I am looking for equivalent in perl

```
static void csignal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {

    char *interrupt_msg[150];
    if (siginfo->si_pid != 0) {
       struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid(siginfo->si_uid);
        if (pwd != 0) {
            sprintf(interrupt_msg, "Received signal '%d' from process '%d' (%s) of user '%s'\n",
                signum, siginfo->si_pid, get_process_name_by_pid(siginfo->si_pid), pwd->pw_name);

        } else {
            sprintf(interrupt_msg, "Received signal '%d' from process '%d' (%s) of user '%d'\n",
               signum, siginfo->si_pid, get_process_name_by_pid(siginfo->si_pid), siginfo->si_uid);

        }

        printf("%s", interrupt_msg);
    }
    if (raise_interrupt) {
        PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyboardInterrupt, interrupt_msg );
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    } else {
        interrupted = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is 'no', because it's a kernel space thing, but I'm not sure I could find a reference for that.

Comment: im able to capture this info in python because i wrote a c extension module which captures it but idk if it can be port to perl

Comment: OK. Well, at a worst case you can inline C into perl. I didn't honestly think the signal handler passed that information though.

Comment: you mean in perl it doesnt? it works on c/python. ive tested myself.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=346477 - I suspect the reason may be because perl does 'safe signals' and any C based solution isn't.

Comment: You query the system _very_ heavily here!  The info you have does not come from the signal itself.

Comment: @ealeon, That information is lost. When you install a signal handler, the actual signal handler installed just increments a counter when the signal comes in. Extra information about the signal isn't stored. The signal handler you provided will eventually be called between Perl ops.

Answer (score 1):

All that our process gets from the kernel is the signal, which I believe is just an integer.  Also, a signal may come from all kinds of events, not just another process. The list given by, for example, `man 7 signal` reveals all kinds of possible sources.

All that is not in the signal.

---

*Update to the question edit*

The added C code doesn't exactly use the signal itself, but queries a whole lot more. A similar approach in Perl is discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296374/how-in-perl-5-can-i-get-the-pid-of-the-process-who-sent-me-a-signal), unearthed by [Syck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5049185/syck) in a comment.

As for digging that information up from `siginfo_t`, the `POSIX::SigAction` is meant to expose those fields, but it apparently doesn't. It may be that you are best off writing your own extension, or try with [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/Inline-C-0.76/lib/Inline/C.pod) as suggested by [sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine SA_SIGINFO and signalfd to find out the pid of process which sent the signal.

See: [How can I tell in Linux which process sent my process a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400530/how-can-i-tell-in-linux-which-process-sent-my-process-a-signal)